# Java - Returning mixed data from a function

Tags: java

I'm not new to programming but I am new to Java. I have an app with a function that needs to return an Integer and a Short value pulled from a database, so I can call the function, then use those two values elsewhere. I've tried a hashmap which I know can do this, but I don't want to iterate anything. It will always be a single "record" found, so one Int, and one Short.

What's the best method for this?

Comment: First, don't use `short`. Second, why would your use a HashMap for 2 values only?

Comment: Any reason to avoid using `short`?

Comment: @CameronSkinner The only reason to use `short` is to save memory. The reason not to use it is that the JVM does not have any arithmetic capabilities for the `short` type: it must convert the `short` into an `int`, do the proper caculation and convert the `int` back to a `short`. There's actually a question on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904857/which-is-better-to-use-short-or-int).

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov: Fair enough. But it's worth noting that if the code is memory-intensive and arithmetic-light then `short` can be a useful choice.

Comment: @CameronSkinner Sure, this needs to be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a helper class, and return that.

```
class MyResults {
    public final short a;
    public final int   b;
    public MyResults(short a, int b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
}


MyResults myMethod() {
    ...
    return new MyResults(42, 666);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A more general solution is to create a `Pair<T1, T2>` class, similar to the tuple construct in ML/OCaml/F# or the `Tuple` classes in C# but not quite as nice (not least because a general solution to this problem loses performance due to boxing/unboxing of primitives):

```
public final class Pair<T1, T2> {
    private final T1 item1;
    private final T2 item2;

    public Pair(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.item2 = item2;
    }

    public T1 getItem1() {
        return item1;
    }

    public T2 getItem2() {
        return item2;
    }
}
```

This class does have the benefit, though, that as long as `T1` and `T2` are immutable, objects of type `Pair` are also immutable.

Comment: This will require using wrapper classes, which take up more memory than primitive classes.

Comment: @RyanAmos You are correct.  I already said that, though: "a general solution to this problem loses performance due to boxing/unboxing of primitives"

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Java doesn't support "out" parameters so there are only a few options, and they're all pretty mucky.

1) Have a struct-ish class for encapsulating the return type:

```
class MixedData {
    public int intValue;
    public short shortValue;
    public MixedData(int intValue, short shortValue) {...}
}

public MixedData foo() {
    return new MixedData(...);
}
```

2) Pass in a struct-ish (or object array, or whatever) as a fake "out" parameter

```
public void foo(MixedData result) {
    result.intValue = ...;
    result.shortValue = ...;
}
```

2.5) In your specific case you could actually abuse the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package and do this:

```
public void foo(AtomicInteger intValue, AtomicInteger shortValue) {
    intValue.set(...);
    shortValue.set(...);
}
```

It gives you a much more C-like signature, but don't do it. Not least because there is no `AtomicShort`.

3) Return an array of objects and document which object is at each index:

```
/** 
 * @return intValue, shortValue
 */
public Object[] foo() {
    return new Object[] {intValue, shortValue};
}
```

Generally the "preferred" option is the first, but option 2 is good in some circumstances, too, especially if you are accumulating data over a series of methods. Passing arrays of objects around is nasty, but it'll work.

Of course you can also pass `Map`s or `Collection`s around, too, if that makes sense for what you're doing.

There is something of a religious war over whether a general purpose `Pair` (or `Tuple`) class is a good idea or not; if it makes sense for your purposes then write a `Pair` class, if not then stick with a specific `MixedData` class.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class containing these two properties, and return an instance of this class.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new object to do this. You can call it whatever you like: ShortIntPair, etc. Probably something more descriptive.

```
public class ShortIntPair {
    public short s;
    public int i;
    public ShortIntPair(int i, short s){
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return an object of class `YourRecordType` that has the two (possibly public) fields you need.